# Multiple segues from one table view controller?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, tableview, segue

So I have a table view controller which lists a list of categories, each category has a parentid which is the id of another category.

By default, all the categories with parentid=0 are shown, and I have ctrl-dragged from the table view cell to the table view controller to link the view controller to itself; and i've written the code to change the contents of the table based on the category that was clicked on. (hope that part makes sense).

Basically, now I've hit a problem.

When I enter a category (or sub-category) with no category children, I want to then navigate to a different view controller, but I can't seem to find a way to create two segues from the table view cell.

Example...

User clicks food and drink from the first list
2nd list displays:

> food
>   drink

"food" is clicked from this sub-list.
Food has no sub-categories, so I want to display all the items for this category, using a different table view controller.

Does this make sense? I have heard about manual segues but I can't seem to get them working.

Answer (score 2):

You can programatically do a segue with:

```
self.navigationController performSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)
```

Comment: Hi Andrei, this is good but how do I set up one of these segues to go to the same view controller? I can ctrl drag from the table view cell onto the table view, but when I try to ctrl-drag from the table view controller to the same table view controller - nothing happens. One of the segues will link back to the same view controller and the other will go off to a different one.

Comment: You don't need to perform a segue to go to the same view controller. Simply reload the tableView with the new data. If you really want to perform a segue, create another tableViewController to segue to. To send data to the next view controller, you need to implement prepareForSegue.